# Showing that the derivative of the integral is the function itself

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

The task at hand is to show that the integral for some function $f$ obeying $\oint f(z) dz = 0$,
\begin{align*}
F(z) = \int_a^{z} f(w) dw,
\end{align*}
is well defined, and that it obeys the relation
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{F(z+h) - F(z)}h = f(z), \tag{$\dagger$}
\end{align*}
that is, the derivative of the integral is well defined to be the function itself.

Assuming I've already proven that the integral is well-defined (i.e. it is unique and it exists), I have to show that the derivative of the integral is the function itself (expression $(\dagger)$). I've managed to formulate a proof which I just handed in as "incomplete, but whatever" since I couldn't figure out what step to take next.

Now here comes the kicker, my TA graded the proof as sufficient and I'm puzzled as to why. Therefore my question is: why is my proof sufficient? Should I argue that I can keep choosing $w-z$ to be smaller so that the limit goes to zero? What's needed to understand my own proof (I know how silly this sounds...).

---

First I calculate what the function $f(z)$ integrated over variable $w$ is from $z$ to $z+h$ (why we're doing this will be apparent later)
\begin{align*}
\int_z^{z+h} f(z) dw = f(z) \int_z^{z+h} dw = h f(z) \Rightarrow f(z) = \frac{\int_z^{z+h} f(z) dw}{h}
\end{align*}
and calculate
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(z+h) - F(z)}h &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_a^{z+h} f(w)dw - \int_a^{z} f(w)dw}h\\
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int^{z+h}_{z} f(w)dw+\int_a^{z} f(w)dw - \int_a^{z} f(w)dw}h\\
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_z^{z+h} f(w)dw}h.
\end{align*}
Now conclude
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(z+h) - F(z)}h -f(z) &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_z^{z+h} [f(w)-f(z)] dw}h.
\end{align*}
If we now use the ML inequality, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\left\lvert \frac{\int_z^{z+h} [f(w)-f(z)] dw}h\right\rvert = \frac1{\lvert h\rvert} \left\lvert\int_z^{z+h} [f(w)-f(z)] \right\rvert dw \leq \frac1{\lvert h\rvert} \varepsilon\lvert h\rvert = \varepsilon,
\end{align*}
for some constant $\varepsilon$, obeying $\lvert f(w)-f(z)\rvert <\varepsilon$ when $\lvert w-z\rvert <\delta$, $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an important piece of information missing here, you don't say what is assumed of the domain of $f$ [you also don't mention that $f$ is assumed to be continuous, but that's inferable from the context alone].

If the domain of $f$ is assumed to be convex (and nonempty, to avoid trivialities), then the only point is that at the end you write "$\lvert \dotsc \rvert \leq \varepsilon$ for some constant $\varepsilon$, obeying $\lvert f(w) - f(z)\rvert < \varepsilon$ when $\lvert w-z\rvert < \delta$, $\delta > 0$". The correct order is that you first pick an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$, and then deduce that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$0 < \lvert h\rvert < \delta \implies \biggl\lvert \frac{F(z+h) - F(z)}{h} - f(z)\biggr\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon.\tag{1}$$

By the continuity of $f$, for the given $\varepsilon$ there is an $\eta > 0$ such that $\lvert w-z\rvert < \eta$ implies $\lvert f(w) - f(z)\rvert < \varepsilon$, and choosing $0 < \delta \leqslant \eta$ so that $\lvert h\rvert < \delta$ guarantees that the straight line segment connecting $z$ and $z+h$ lies in the domain of $f$ then yields $(1)$ following your computation - of course for a convex domain, the latter condition is trivially satisfied, so one chooses $\delta = \eta$ (and doesn't even mention $\eta$). One can also put that informally at the end, writing something like "$\lvert\dotsc\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$ for any given $\varepsilon > 0$ if $0 < \lvert h\rvert < \delta$ for an appropriate $\delta > 0$". In a complex analysis course, one might assume that it is known what "appropriate" means here, and that it can be correctly translated into [more] formal language. But it may be necessary to make the "appropriate" more explicit if one can't count on that assumption.

If the domain of $f$ is not assumed to be convex, there are some more small explanations missing, and your TA has been a bit magnanimous if they awarded full marks for it (the essential bits are there, so I wouldn't deduct much, but without a convexity assumption I'd have deducted some points).

First thing is that it's not said what $\int_a^z f(w)\,dw$ means. If the domain of $f$ is convex, or just star-shaped with respect to $a$, we have the standard interpretation that it should be the integral over the straight line segment connecting $a$ and $z$, and no explanatory remark is necessary. If the domain of $f$ is an arbitrary (nonempty) connected open set, it ought to be said that one chooses a path $\gamma$ (sufficiently regular for integration, that could mean piecewise $C^1$; rectifiable would suffice) from $a$ to $z$ and lets $\int_a^z f(w)\,dw$ denote $\int_{\gamma} f(w)\,dw$. Since the value of the integral is independent from the chosen path (as was shown before), the short-hand of dropping the path and mentioning only start and end points is legitimate.

Next, in your calculation you split $\int_a^{z+h} f(w)\,dw$ into $\int_z^{z+h} f(w)\,dw + \int_a^z f(w)\,dw$. The splitting is legitimate by the premise that the integral of $f$ over all closed paths shall vanish, and if the domain of $f$ is convex, there is no problem, as we can assume the standard interpretation of integrating over a straight line segment for the integrals. If the domain is not convex, the question is about the interpretation of $\int_z^{z+h} f(w)\,dw$. If that is to mean the integration over an arbitrary path from $z$ to $z+h$, that is valid, but doesn't help in the end. To reach the conclusion (by way of the ML inequality) we need $\int_z^{z+h} f(w)\,dw$ to mean the integral over the straight line segment connecting $z$ and $z+h$ (strictly, we can also take some other family of paths, but we need that the length of the path is bounded by $C\cdot \lvert h\rvert$ for some constant $C$, taking the straight line segment is most convenient and easy). So, without a convexity assumption, you should - at about that place - say that from now on you assume $\lvert h\rvert$ small enough that the straight line segment from $z$ to $z+h$ lies in the domain of $f$. (The domain is open, so there's an $r > 0$ such that the disk $D_r(z) = \{ w \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert w-z\rvert < r\}$ lies in the domain of $f$, then $\lvert h\rvert < r$ guarantees that.)

To recapitulate: First one picks an $r > 0$ so that for $\lvert h\rvert < r$, the straight line segment from $z$ to $z+h$ is contained in the domain of $f$. Then one uses the premise "$\oint f(z)\,dz = 0$" to see that - for $\lvert h\rvert < r$ - one has

$$F(z+h) - F(z) = \int_z^{z+h} f(w)\,dw,$$

where the integral means the integral over the straight line segment. Finally, one uses the continuity of $f$ at $z$ to have for every $\varepsilon > 0$ a $0 < \delta \leqslant r$ with $\lvert w-z\rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(w) - f(z)\rvert < \varepsilon$. The ML inequality then shows that for $0 < \lvert h\rvert < \delta$ we have

$$\biggl\lvert \frac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h} - f(z)\biggr\rvert < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth explanation. Would it change anything if I assumed $f$ is continuous on a domain $D$ and that $\oint f(z)dz =0$ for every simply closed curve $C$?

Comment: Convexity was never mentioned and I'm not sure how to approach that part of the problem.

Comment: No, only assuming that $\oint f(z)\,dz = 0$ for every _simple_ closed curve suffices, that wouldn't change anything significant. You could either restrict your considerations to paths that combine to simple closed curves, or show that the "simple closed" case implies the "closed" case. Depending on what machinery you can use and what regularity you demand of the curves, the technical details can be annoying, but if you only consider piecewise $C^1$ curves, it's not too intricate.

Comment: If you also require that the derivative of the curve vanishes nowhere, a decomposition of a closed curve into finitely many simple closed curves isn't hard to get. If convexity isn't given, then you need to say at some point that you only consider points close enough to $z$ that the straight line segment between $z$ and $w$ is contained in $D$. That's all there is to it, but it needs to be mentioned.

Comment: Doesn't $\oint f(z) dz = 0$ for every simple* closed curve imply analyticity, therefore making it $C^\infty$? I have a feeling I'm walking through a mine field.. In regard to your second comment: why do we require that a straight line segment from $z$ to $w$ should be contained in $D$? Could I otherwise take a path for which the value of the path integral is not necessarily zero (since the path is not in $D$)?

Comment: @1010011010 Yes,  it does imply analyticity (we don't even need all simple closed curves, boundaries of triangles suffice), but that $f$ is the derivative of its integral is usually part of the proof of that fact [off the top of my head, I can't think of a proof not using this]. If $D$ is convex, it suffices to demand that $\int_{\partial \Delta} f(z)\,dz = 0$ for all (closed) triangles $\Delta \subset D$, but for general $D$ we need more. The point of requiring that the straight line segment is contained in $D$ is that otherwise we lose control over the length of the path from $z$ to $z+h$.

Comment: The ML inequality gives us $\bigl\lvert \int_{\gamma} f(w) - f(z)\,dw\bigr\rvert \leqslant L(\gamma)\cdot \sup \{ \lvert f(\gamma(t)) - f(z)\rvert : t \in [a,b]\}$, where $[a,b]$ is the parameter interval of $\gamma$, but knowing that $\lvert f(w) - f(z)\rvert < \varepsilon$ on the trace of $\gamma$ doesn't help if we can't control the length of $\gamma$. If we take the straight line segment, we know $L(\gamma) = \lvert h\rvert$ and we're happy.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comments on the proof. Convexity was mentioned only very briefly throughout the course so I'm guessing we're assuming convexity throughout the course. As a last question (since you didn't mention it explicitly in your answer): I can choose a very small $\varepsilon$ such that aforementioned $\delta$ implies the statement given by you. Does that mean I can choose $\varepsilon = 0$, such that $\lvert f(z) - f(w) \rvert = 0$, showing that the limit $h\rightarrow\infty$ goes to zero? I'm particularly insecure about that step.

Comment: No, you can't choose $\varepsilon = 0$, since $\lvert f(w) - f(z)\rvert = 0$ for all relevant $w$ would mean that $f$ is constant on some neighbourhood of $z$, and since $z$ was arbitrary and $D$ connected, that means $f$ is constant on $D$. But of course few functions are constant. The thing one needs to show is that (for every $z\in D$) _for every_ $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < \lvert h\rvert < \delta$ implies $\bigl\lvert \frac{F(z+h) - F(z)}{h} - f(z)\bigr\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$.

Comment: The crux of the proof is that we can choose $\delta > 0$ so that $\lvert w-z\rvert < \delta$ implies $\lvert f(w) - f(z)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$ (which we can do by continuity of $f$), and such that we have a path in $D$ from $z$ to $z+h$ for $0 < \lvert h\rvert < \delta$ that stays in the disk $\{ w : \lvert w-z\rvert < \delta\}$ and has a length bounded by a constant multiple of $\lvert h\rvert$. The simplest way to achieve that is to take $\delta$ small enough that the straight line segment remains in $D$.